# MBP 15-inch Late 2017 Swollen Battery

Tags: macbook-pro

I have this MBP that I bought on early 2018. And as of now (March 2020) I just noticed the battery appears to be swollen. Basically, the lid will not close all the way, and if I lay the laptop on my desk there's a little bit of wobbling when I type.

I'm under lockdown right now and can't get it fixed / buy another one. So my question is basically how long can I use it until it won't work anymore and is there anything I can do on my own to mitigate this problem?

Comment: You *must* replace it because it's trapping gasses. At a minimum, it can damage your Mac.  It could also cause thermal runaway.  If you have the tech skills, remove it.  If not,  there are companies that you can mail it to that will do this for you. [Rossman Group in NYC](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/) is a good one (not affiliated, just happy customer)

Comment: @Allan I can't mail it anywhere right now or buy a replacement. Do you think it would be a good idea to run the computer without the battery?

Comment: You can run it without a battery, but where are you located?  We're under quarantine here in FL, but I make daily runs to the post office with zero issues.  I also just had a headset delivered from Amazon, so products are getting through.